# Need to send DTMF tone from custom dialer

Tags: android, dtmf

I know this question has been asked many times here on stack , but I would like to confirm this as i need to be sure off . Can we pass DTMF tone using our custom dialer?

I found one very interesting link on git and i managed to setup the code and able to make build .

**here is the link of apk** :-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r12qewmz659bf2j/DTMF_demo.apk?dl=0

And the code from where I generate the above build :-

https://github.com/rajeshincorp/UD_SendDtmfToneOverActiveCall

I need your guidance here

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and I could sent a DTMF tone in the beggining of the call. If the call was already active, I could not send the DTMF tone, only sending, starting the call. You can send "," to delay the caracters sent, for example, to interact with certain interact voice response.